# Clone with OuterHTML, reformat and then copy/paste

Tags: formatting, clone

So I have a block of content I am cloning with OuterHTML. I would like to know if there's a way I could take that generated clode, clean it and wrap it around a prettify related plugin. Basically, I would like to create a dynamic copy/paste block based on a previously generated HTML.

I have searched everywhere but it seems I am not using the correct search terms or maybe this is not possible?

Thanks for your help

Comment: That seems fine as you describe it. Have you tried it? Are you running into specific implementation issues?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. At the moment, I have being able to clone the content. But I don't know how to "clean" it so I can then wrap it around prettify.

Comment: It all depends on the source HTML you're expecting and how you want to 'clean' it. Try looking for JS regular expressions for removing attributes from HTML strings as a start.